# read the last line twice

Tags: file, stream

```
ifstream infile("score.txt", ios::in);
int score;
while(infile.good()){
    infile >> score;
    cout << score << endl;
}
```

I tried to read scores from a file and print them. But the last score is always being read twice. I also tried some other condition such as while(!infile.eof()), but nothing changes. I am really confused by this.

The score file looks like the following:
78
23
43
23
54

The "54" is always read and printed twice.

Answer (score 0):

try this  one......

```
ifstream infile("score.txt",ios::in);
int score;

infile >> score; // before loop read 1 time

while(infile.eof())
{
 infile >> score;
 cout << score << endl;
}
```